# Find all Self referenced M:M with zero children in Grails

Tags: mysql, grails

I am trying to create a query to return all objects with no children using the following model:

```
class Message {
    static hasMany = [ children: Message ]
    static belongsTo = [ parent: Message ]
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried Message.findAll("from Message m where m.children = null")?

Comment: Yeah, I've tried that... doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "is empty" in HQL for this:

```
Message.executeQuery('from Message m where m.children is empty')
```